# Staff of Flowers only sprouts harmless and nonmagical flowers, but what does this mean exactly?

Tags: magic-items

For those of you that aren't familiar with this item:

"This wooden staff has 10 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 charge from the staff and cause a flower to sprout from a patch of earth or soil within 5 feet of you, or from the staff itself. Unless you choose a specific kind of flower, the staff creates a mild-scented daisy .The flower is harmless and nonmagical, and it grows or withers as a normal flower would."

But what counts as a harmless or nonmagical flower? The Powderpuff, for instance, is harmless as a flower but can be dried and powdered to make an explosive substance. The flower itself is harmless, though, right? Or is harmful and/or magical potency restricted as well?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Take the [tour].  Which game (and edition) are you asking about?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: If you're asking about D&D 5e, as I suspect, you can indicate this by editing the [dnd-5e] tag into your question.